# CamelExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly, java-11, apache-camel-3

I am using JDK 11, apache camel 3.4.0 and WildFly 20.0.1.Final and have following error in the wildfly console.

```
10:39:19,982 ERROR [com.interfaces.processors.common.GarbageProcessor] (default task-1) process().EXCEPTION_CAUGHT : CamelExceptionCaught | EXCEPTION_HANDLED : CamelExceptionHandled
10:39:19,983 INFO  [com.utility.util.IntegrationUtility] (default task-1) generateErrorResponse().detailedTrace : org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:425)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:170)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:66)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:110)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:107)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:185)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:413)
    deployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices.getEndpointService(IntegrationServices.java:165)
    deployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getEndpointService$$super(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)
    
10:39:19,988 ERROR [com.utility.util.IntegrationUtility] (default task-1) process().errorResponseBody : {"Success":false,"RESULT":{"condition":"bad"},"Exception":{"message":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-1]","causedBy":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel","detailedTrace":"org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:425)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:170)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:66)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:110)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:107)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:185)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:413)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices.getEndpointService(IntegrationServices.java:165)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getEndpointService$$super(Unknown Source)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tjava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\torg.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)\n\t... 419 more"},"OUTPUTS":{"FAILURE_REASON":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-1], causedBy java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel"}}
10:39:20,952 INFO  [org.camunda.feel.FeelEngine] (default task-1) Engine created. [value-mapper: CompositeValueMapper(List(org.camunda.feel.impl.JavaValueMapper@5f8ab78f)), function-provider: org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.scala.function.CustomFunctionTransformer@25a6e2c5, clock: SystemClock, configuration: Configuration(false)]
10:39:22,104 INFO  [ERROR] (default task-1) Exchange[Id: ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-2, ExchangePattern: InOnly, Properties: {CamelExceptionCaught=org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID--Dev-1607317759951-0-2], CamelFailureEndpoint=direct://groovy, CamelFailureRouteId=route4, CamelFatalFallbackErrorHandler=[route4], CamelFilterMatched=true, CamelToEndpoint=log://ERROR?showAll=true}, Headers: {clientId=, configData={"messageId":"pingTestOutputJSON_assessor","groovyFile":"pingTestExecutor/pingTestOutputJSON#MDSL_assessor.gsh","fieldMaps":[{"id":35,"inputFields":[{"id":62,"name":"summary","fromJsonField":"RESULT.detail.summary","type":"string"}],"fieldMapType":"RES"},{"id":36,"name":"INPUTS","inputFields":[{"id":63,"name":"token","fromJsonField":"INPUTS.TOKEN","type":"string"}],"fieldMapType":"REQ"}],"clientId":"","decorator":{"id":1,"mode":"output","decoratorType":"RESPONSE_DECORATOR","decoratorName":"commonOutput","decoratorKeywords":[{"id":1,"keyword":{"id":1,"keywordName":"detail.summary","dataType":"string"}},{"id":2,"keyword":{"id":2,"keywordName":"detail.token","dataType":"string"}},{"id":3,"keyword":{"id":3,"keywordName":"detail.success","dataType":"boolean"}},{"id":4,"keyword":{"id":4,"keywordName":"detail.dispatchInstructions","dataType":"string"}},{"id":5,"keyword":{"id":5,"keywordName":"detail.testResult","dataType":"boolean"}},{"id":6,"keyword":{"id":6,"keywordName":"detail.ifmsSummary","dataType":"string"}},{"id":7,"keyword":{"id":7,"keywordName":"detail.nextAction","dataType":"string"}},{"id":8,"keyword":{"id":8,"keywordName":"detail.nextActionCommand","dataType":"string"}},{"id":9,"keyword":{"id":9,"keywordName":"detail.failureReason","dataType":"string"}},{"id":10,"keyword":{"id":10,"keywordName":"detail.failureReasonIfms","dataType":"string"}},{"id":12,"keyword":{"id":12,"keywordName":"detail.detailOutput","dataType":"string"}}]}}, doLogFiles=true, dontLogErrorFiles=true, messageId=pingTestOutputJSON_assessor, messageName=GroovyAccessor, RAW_BODY={"INPUTS":{"traceId":"ca67daac5783dbc2a694efb97b5a5a55:a694efb97b5a5a55:0:0","authKey":"446246d5-8c52-401b-a69f-8163854d80f3","conditionPass":false,"requestHeaderMap":{},"circuitIds":"EVC00026166","KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID":"Client","FAILURE_REASON":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-1], causedBy java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel","causedBy":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel","message":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-1]","detailedTrace":"org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:425)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:170)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:66)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:110)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:107)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:185)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:413)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices.getEndpointService(IntegrationServices.java:165)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getEndpointService$$super(Unknown Source)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tjava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\torg.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)\n\t... 419 more","Success":false,"processDefinitionKey":"pingTest","Authorization":"bearer ....]
10:39:22,105 ERROR [com.interfaces.processors.common.GarbageProcessor] (default task-1) process().EXCEPTION_CAUGHT : CamelExceptionCaught | EXCEPTION_HANDLED : CamelExceptionHandled
10:39:22,105 INFO  [com.utility.util.IntegrationUtility] (default task-1) generateErrorResponse().detailedTrace : org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:425)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:170)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:66)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:110)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:107)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:185)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172)
    org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:413)
    deployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices.getEndpointService(IntegrationServices.java:165)
    deployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getEndpointService$$super(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)
    
10:39:22,105 ERROR [com.utility.util.IntegrationUtility] (default task-1) process().errorResponseBody : {"Success":false,"RESULT":{"condition":"bad"},"Exception":{"message":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-2]","causedBy":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel","detailedTrace":"org.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:47)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:425)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:170)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:702)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:616)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:66)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:212)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:110)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:107)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:185)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172)\n\torg.apache.camel.core@3.4.0//org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:413)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices.getEndpointService(IntegrationServices.java:165)\n\tdeployment.-integration-services.war//com.integration.services.ep.IntegrationServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getEndpointService$$super(Unknown Source)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tjava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\torg.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)\n\t... 419 more"},"OUTPUTS":{"FAILURE_REASON":"org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Mihan-Dev-1607317759951-0-2], causedBy java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/tooling/model/ComponentModel"}}
```

I have already added the following dependency in the pom.xml and I have tried making the scope "provided" for camel-tooling-model dependency after copying extracted WildFly-Camel 12.0.0 to the WildFly installation. But I get the same error as above.

```
    <properties>
            <version.camel>3.4.0</version.camel>
    </properties>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-tooling-model</artifactId>
        <version>${version.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I found (when debugging) that the following line is the exact place where the exception occurs and observed requestBodyAndHeaders method in ProducerTemplate interface throws the CamelExecutionException.

```java
responseBody = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:cbr", requestBody, headers, String.class);
```

And here is the ContentBasedRouter class

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("content_based_router")
public class ContentBasedRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:error"));
        from("direct:cbr")
                .choice()
                .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-http"))
                    .to("direct:http")
               .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-https"))
                   .to("direct:https")
                .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-groovy"))
                    .to("direct:groovy")
                .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-jdbc"))
                    .to("direct:jdbc")
                .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-soap"))
                    .to("direct:soap")
                .when(header("routeId").isEqualTo("direct-xmlrpc"))
                    .to("direct:xmlrpc")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("direct:misc");
    }
}
```

Highly appreciate your advice to fix this issue!

Comment: What exactly is `direct:cbr` doing? Maybe you can share the full error stack trace from the WildFly server log instead of pasting the screenshot.

Comment: @JamesNetherton, we are calling that router to invoke other routers. I just added the code snippet for that class.

Comment: Can you get the full stack trace so we can see where the `NoClassDefFoundError` is occurring? The truncated trace doesn't reveal much.

Comment: @JamesNetherton, Added more wildfly trace. Sorry, this is the amount of trace I'm allowed to share.